# Load datasets and store it in another file using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, dataset

How can I read all images from datasets and store it in another location using opencv.

Comment: Please specify which dataset you are working on, what format they are stored in (image files in single folder, images within multiple folder, or some specific format etc)

Comment: It's an image dataset

Comment: All files are of type jpg and in same folder

Comment: than just copy the files. why you need opencv?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to read the files in a folder.

```
import glob
import cv2
for file in glob.glob('source/*.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    filename = 'destination/'+file.split('source\\')[1]
    cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
```

[Split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) function of python can be used to obtain the image-name which is then written to the destination folder.

*NOTE*- If the folders are not in the current working directory please specify the absolute path. For more on absolute and relative paths refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import cv2

SOURCE_FOLDER = "a"
DESTINATION_FOLDER = "b"

for image_file_name in os.listdir(SOURCE_FOLDER):
    #  get full path to image file
    image_path = os.path.join(SOURCE_FOLDER, image_file_name)

    #  read image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    #  store image in another folder
    image_write_path = os.path.join(DESTINATION_FOLDER, image_file_name)
    cv2.imwrite(image_write_path, img)
```